# OpenWRT: Reconnect/Unbrick Archer A7 v5 (similar to C7)

Tags: openwrt, dd-wrt

I've configured the `Archer A7 v5` to work with OpenWRT and it worked fine. I've used the TFTP method.

Last week I tried to install a firewall on the run. After trying different methods. I found [this guide](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/firewall/fw3_configurations/dns_ipset) copy-paste it -- see the print-screens below -- and since then the router is not accessible anymore. I mean: it starts, it shows that the wifi and the ethernet-cable are activated. However, it does not attribute any IP address regardless if you connect by ethernet or wifi.

I know, I should not carelessly copy-paste if I do not understand exactly what I'm doing. However, I relied on being able to reset and restart everything.

What I've tried
After failing to connect by `ssh` or `web-gui` I've tried to reinstall the firmware via `FTP`-method. It doesen't work. Since I've done the initial installation 6 months ago I'm not sure if I might missing some detail. Additionally I moved from Debian to Arch-Linux and maybe there are some differences inside the network settings of my PC.

Also the OpenWRT DD-WRT pages are somewhat contradictoriy about the specific settings. Like the required IP-address: [a](https://openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/archer_a7_v5#installation_using_the_tftp_method), [b](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/TP_Link_Archer_A7v5#TFTP_RECOVERY_TO_REVERT_BACK_TO_STOCK).

Do you have some idea/experience about how to resolve the problem?

[image: printscreen-1]

[image: printscreen-2]

[image: printscreen-3]

Answer (score 0):

I literally *just* finished doing this myself.

Regarding the IP addresses:

- Your TFTP server must be `192.168.0.66/24`
- When the router boots, it will assign itself the address `192.168.0.86/24`

Convince yourself that you can `tftp` to `192.168.0.66` (probably using another computer) to ensure no issues with firewalls.  Then power off the router, hold down the recessed reset button with a pin, then power back on and hold 10 seconds until the rightmost icon (with the two arrows) lights up.  Then release the reset button.

The router will attempt to fetch the file `ArcherC7v5_tp_recovery.bin` (I watched the TFTP traffic on my laptop using WireShark).

After a few seconds, the power icon should begin flashing and after a couple minutes (< 5) the icon for the connected ethernet port should light up (I had the router being flashed connected on port #3).  At this point, power off the router, then power it back up again and it should come up with address `192.168.1.1` and you can connect to the web GUI.

I ran the `tftp` server on macos 10.14.6 using the instructions [here](https://ramsgaard.me/macos-tftp-server/).

Of note: I initially had the router connected directly to my laptop via an ethernet cable, but I didn't have any success until I connected the TP-Link device and my laptop to another switch I had available.  YMMV.